# msal intercepting a redirect on client side

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, jwt

Using Microsoft.Identity.Web with SPA and Vue and using `[AuthorizeWithScopes]` on Controllers.

This correctly work in the sense that when the token in the cache has expired I'm getting a 302 statuscode and getting the correct location set in the response header to be used for redirect. Seen in the browser network tab on the response header.

BUT my problem is just.. I can't seem to get the location on the client side (however weird that sounds). I tried to intercept the response, but it doesn't contain location in header, it seem to fail beforehand.

I tried

```
   OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
 {
    if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
   {
    if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    }

    context.HandleResponse();
}

return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

But context has no location now. Only if I delete context.HandleResponse() and let it go through, I can see the response header contains the location in browser. When I try to intercept the response on the client the response has nothing. I also get CORS errors (which is not something I can do anything about), but the point is also to set a 401 and then use the location on the clientside to redirect (instead of from server side).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could not resolve this in the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider, since the location is not present at this point. Only after it has tried the redirect (not before) it will create the location. The location contains the microsoft.login redirect url to make an authentication against.

So my solution was to "catch" the redirect request in our globalexceptionhandler middleware instead ([inspiration here](https://code-maze.com/global-error-handling-aspnetcore/))

In our service registration:

```cs
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
                {
                    if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                    {
                        if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            
                          // the context does not contain any location from headers at this point :(
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                            ctx.Properties.RedirectUri = ctx.Request.Headers["referer"]; // When RedirectUri is set here the location in the header will include it.
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }

                        ctx.HandleResponse();
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
```

Backend inside GlobalExceptionMiddleware.cs:

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IEnumerable<IExceptionHandler> exceptionHandlers, IAuthorizedUserContext userContext)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context).ConfigureAwait(false);

                await HandleMsalUiRequiredException(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            // ..... catches for different types of exceptions
        }
```

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Handles 302 redirect to login provider requests when an invalid token (e.g. a cached token) is used.
        /// This method aborts the call to login from backend and sends the response to client for it to handle instead.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
        private async Task HandleMsalUiRequiredException(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 302 && context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Location") && context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            {
                var message = $"Jwt token in cache is invalid for User: {context.User.Identity.Name}. Acquiring new token.";
                var ex = new MsalUiRequiredException("401", message);
                _logger.LogWarning(ex, message);
                await WriteHttpErrorResult(context, ex, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, ex.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
```

Frontend interception for incoming responses (using axios/vue, typescript and an nswag generated client):

```js
protected transformResult(url: string, response: AxiosResponse, processor: (response: AxiosResponse) => any) {
       
       // Intercept msal jwt cache authorization error and then
       // acquire a new token by redirecting to login which will redirect back to user's current location.
       if (response.status === 401 && response.data.ExceptionType === 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException' && response.headers['location'] !== null)
        {
            window.location.href = response.headers['location'];
        }
        
        return processor(response); 
    }
```

This will then intercept the msal exception and do the redirect on clientside to avoid any CORS issues.

It works, but any suggestions / better practices are more than welcome.